# User Pool with Cognito using IAM Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I have created an admin user on my IAM and I created a user pool. I would like to add this admin user into my user pool. Is it possible?

2. quick question; I want integrate my user pool into Cognito. I read [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) chapter from documenation. 
   I have already identity pool which is set up with Facebook, Google, Twitter etc. It obviously has User Pool ID and App client ID. So Should I override it or create a new identity pool to use my user pool? 
   If I override, will this cause problem on my facebook, google users?

Answer (score 1):

Users in cognito and users in IAM are not the same type of users, so no. But you could create a user with the same username in cognito instead.

What I think that refers to is to connect your IAM user to the federated identities and thus applying the same user role policies.

Comment: yep, I would create same user in app pool but i wanted to make sure if it is possible in order to avoid duplication. thanks for answering.

Comment: your second comment is not clear for me. are you saying that userpool and other providers like (fb, google etc) can be in the same identity pool?

Comment: Yes. A user pool is just another identity provider, from the point of view of the identity pool. You can have a user pool linked with any other public provider, on it's own, or any combination.